# What sort of Image should I use in my model, when the aim is to display this image in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am in a situation where I am storing images as byte arrays in a SQL database. I am using EF, and so have a byte array automatic property in my model, which is then committed to the database via code first.

I want to put a read only property which is an Image into my model, and convert the byte array to an Image when the get accessor is called. Two questions:

1. What sort of Image should I use? Should it be a System.Drawing image, or a newer BitmapImage?
2. Will this cause any problems in regards to code-first and EF?

I can post code if you wish, but I didn't think it was necessary, if anybody wants to see my code, just leave a comment.

Comment: Do you want to do any processing on the Image after you have convert the byte array? Or the only purpruse is to show it your view with an `<img>`? Because you can do that without any conversion... with introducing an `ImageController` with a `Show` method which serves directly your images form the db to the view without any conversion

Comment: @nemesv Thanks, in the end I found the [WebImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx) class and used that, it takes a byte array in one of it's constructors and Razor seems to like it, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What sort of Image should I use? Should it be a System.Drawing
>   image, or a newer BitmapImage?

None of them. You should use a byte array (`byte[]`).

> 2) Will this cause any problems in regards to code-first and EF?

I don't think so. I am not an expert with EF but I think it should be possible to map a `byte[]` property to the corresponding `varbinary(max)` column in your database.

Now back to your original question about showing an image and having a property on your view model. Even if you do that you cannot display this byte array property as an image inside your view unless you use the [`data uri scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which is not widely supported by all browsers. Here's how this might look like if you decide to go that route:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image))" alt="some image">
```

But if you are looking for a solution that will work across all browsers as an alternative you could design a controller action that will fetch your image from the database as a byte array and then stream it to the response. Next from your view you could reference this action inside an `<img>` tag.

Let's take an example:

```
public ActionResult Image(int id)
{
    byte[] imageData = ... go query your database to retrieve the corresponding
                           image record using the id
    return File(imageData, "image/png");
}
```

and then inside your main view simply point an `<img>` tag to this controller action:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "SomeController", new { id = Model.Id })">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was struggling with the WebImage class before you answered the question, I will go this route now.